# laravel 5.2 timeout handling

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I'm using the Auth in laravel 5.2 and want to know how to handle the timeout better. At the moment I'm using this function in the controller to handle the auth

```
    private function checkAuth()
    {
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        abort(404);
    }

    if (Auth::user()->clientId <> 100) {
        abort(403, 'Unauthorised Action - you are not authorized to see that');
    }

    }
```

I have the timeout set to 15 minutes and would like to get a redirect working when the timeout occurs. I want the redirect to take you to the login page with a warning that you have been timed out. I would also like to redirect after re-login to the original page.

Comment: Set a `last_action` property on your `User` model, and make a filter applied to all routes that checks the property and redirects or updates it

Comment: thanks patrick, but do you have any code to help me acheive this? i dont have a filter.php in laravel 5.2!